# 32 bits and 64 bits architecture

Tags: types, architecture, character, bit

In here, the results turn out to be 3 and 1, which makes sense to me. However, when the code is run on 64 bits architecture, the result becomes 3 and 2. Could you explain why this happens?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(int* a)
{
    int len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    printf("%d", len);
}

int main(void) {
    int a[]= {11, 22, 33};
int len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
printf("%d\n", len);
    print(a);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof(int*)` on 64-bit is going to be 8 bytes, while only 4 bytes on 32-bit. `sizeof(int)` might be 32-bits in both cases.

So for the 32-bit case:

```
int len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);    // (12/4) = 3
int len = sizeof(int*)/sizeof(int); //  (4/4) = 1
```

For the 64-bit case:

```
int len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);    // (12/4) = 3
int len = sizeof(int*)/sizeof(int); //  (8/4) = 2
```

Perhaps you are confused about this part:

```
void print(int* a)
{
    int len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    ...
}
```

`a` above degrades to a pointer, `int*`. Using `sizeof` on it is giving you the size of the pointer to the array, not the contents of the array.